# Randomized pair assignment for testing

Tags: learning, behavior, test

##### Scenario

Take a group of students. During the school/academic year, they will be assigned several tests (ideally one less than the number of students). Usually, students are tested and graded individually (control group). In this scenario, however, for every test, they would be randomly assigned to another student. The test result of the pair is assigned to each pair member. At the end of the year, the final grades are set based on individual performance.

##### Examples

- Top performers remain top performers: if they are ready to excel at each test, they will pass with flying colors regardless of who is their pair assignment - bottom or top performer.
- bottom performers are free-riding the top performers, but results remain mediocre when they are assigned to other bottom performers. Hence after averaging the results, they will remain bottom performers.

##### Hypothesis

- The average performance and/or frame-of-mind will be worse than in a control group due to the accumulation of negative emotions: top performers are angry with bottom performers. Bottom performers have a sense of shame for prohibiting top performers from achieving good results.
- Does this change in time when students begin to understand the system?
- In a larger time unit, does any positive or negative effect hold at all?
- Does the system influence positively learning how to cooperate? How to test for cooperation skills effectively?
- Do worse students, driven by either shame or a sense of shame, can have better results when tested individually at the end of the year (when compared with the control group of students)?

##### Questions

Does any research touch on similarly designed experiments results?